# Weird behaviour of gcc 4.6 compiler

Tags: c++, gcc

This code:

```
template<class Int_T, long long Min, unsigned long long Max>
class Int_Core
{
static_assert(Check_Range<Minimum>::check(Min,std::numeric_limits<Int_T>::min()),"INCORRECT Min range.");
static_assert(Check_Range<Maximum>::check(Max,std::numeric_limits<Int_T>::max()),"INCORRECT Max range.");
}
```

The error I'm getting is on second static_assert telling me that non-const expression has been used. But **If I change 'Max' to 'Min'** in this second assertion it does compile without problems. What's going on?
Error:
**error: non-constant condition for static assertion**

Those are helper classes/fncs:

```
//this is Int_Core.h file

struct Minimum
{/*eb*/};
struct Maximum
{/*eb*/};

/**Checks if given range is within boundary*/
template<class Range>
struct Check_Range;

template<>
struct Check_Range<Minimum>
{
template<class Value,class Limit>
static constexpr bool check(Value val,Limit limit)
{
    return greater_than_or_equal_with(val,limit);
}
};

template<>
struct Check_Range<Maximum>
{
template<class Value,class Limit>
static constexpr bool check(Value val,Limit limit)
{
    return greater_than_or_equal_with(val,limit);
}
};

constexpr bool greater_than(long long signed_,unsigned long long unsigned_)
{
//   unsigned long long mask = 0x8000000000000000LL;
//   bool is_negative = signed_ & mask;
//   if (is_negative)
//   {
//
//       return false;
//   }
//   else
//   {
//      return (signed_ > unsigned_);
//   }
//
   return (signed_ & 0x8000000000000000LL) ? false : (signed_ > unsigned_);
}

constexpr bool equal_with(long long signed_,unsigned long long unsigned_)
{
//   unsigned long long mask = 0x8000000000000000LL;
//   bool is_negative = signed_ & mask;
//   if (is_negative)
//   {
//
//       return false;
//   }
//   else
//   {
//      return (signed_ == unsigned_);
//   }
//This line is == to the commented code above (constexpr must have just return statement)
   return (signed_ & 0x8000000000000000LL) ? false : (signed_ == unsigned_);
}

constexpr bool greater_than_or_equal_with(long long signed_,unsigned long long unsigned_)
{
    return (greater_than(signed_,unsigned_) || equal_with(signed_,unsigned_));
}
```

Update:

```
#include "Int_Core.h"
    int main()
    {
       Int_Core<unsigned char,1,-50> a;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide any testcase?

Comment: @Griwes I don't have any testcases yet. Just paste and try to compile it. I'll update my post with main fnc.

Comment: Just as a note, your test functions are incredibly platform dependent and non-portable.

Comment: Having a class template that can act as signed or unsigned integer depending on instantiation, adds complexity. Things get much simpler when you separate those two cases. Probably you don't need the unsigned variant anyway.

Comment: @KerrekSB any suggestions how to make them portable and platform independent most welcome ;)

Comment: @smallB: Simply don't rely on particular sizes and implementations of signedness... if you're only concerned about integral types, I'd just do everything with templates, without constexpr-functions.

Comment: @KerrekSB how would you statically assert then?

Comment: I've just discovered that if I remove 'unsigned' from second template argument, so I'll make long long Max the following example compiles. I assume compiler error in that case. How can I report bug for GCC?

Comment: @smallB: Same, with `static_assert`. I'd just make the checker a templaty thing, like `template <typename T, T a, T b> struct less_than { static const bool value = a < b; };` or something like that.

Comment: @KerrekSB operator < will fail when comparing unsigned with signed in corner cases.

Comment: @smallB: You can get more sophisticated with various `make_signed` and `is_signed` trait checks. Too much to type in a comment, though :-)

Comment: @smallB: simply taking the code and compiling it does not work, there are at least headers etc. mising. It would really be easier for everyone to try it when you had a single paste that can compile and exhibit the problematic behaviour, then more people will be able to have a look at it.

Comment: @KerrekSB it doesn't matter if you use type_traits - it (operator <) still doesn't behave correctly in corner cases.

Comment: @smallB: It is worse now, since it isnt a single paste. and it is still missing includes e.g. for std::numeric_limits.

Comment: @smallB:  Although GCC in this case decided to trigger the assert, the C++ standard allows different behavior between signed and unsigned integer types ( http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html , the section on signed integer overflow; simply put unsigned overflow is well defined, but signed overflow is undefined, and compilers **do** take advantage of the difference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a compiler bug in gcc 4.6.0, gcc 4.6.1 correctly triggers the static_assert.

Comment: @smallB: Thats how it is when you want to use bleeding edge features/technology.

Comment: I'm ok with that ;) always something to do.